# Use tikz to position nodes relative to bottom edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a set of steps using a TikZ picture. I tried to use the `positioning` library to position the steps next to each other like this:

[image]

(Not for scale, the bottom edges should align)

So I did this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rectangle,             align=center, minimum height=2cm] (1) {\textbf{1} \\ Step};
  \node[draw, rectangle, right=of 1, align=center, minimum height=3cm] (2) {\textbf{2} \\ Step};
  \node[draw, rectangle, right=of 2, align=center, minimum height=4cm] (3) {\textbf{3} \\ Step};
  \node[draw, rectangle, right=of 3, align=center, minimum height=5cm] (4) {\textbf{4} \\ Step};
  \node[draw, rectangle, right=of 4, align=center, minimum height=6cm] (5) {\textbf{5} \\ Step};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But it looks like it aligns the node centers, instead of the bottom edges:

[image]

That's not step-like at all. How can I do that (without using `at` to position each node manually)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm,
                 minimum height=#1, align=center},
node distance = 0mm and 5mm
                    ]
\node[box=2cm] (1) {\textbf{1} \\ Step};
\node[box=3cm, above right=of 1.south east] (2) {\textbf{2} \\ Step};
\node[box=4cm, above right=of 2.south east] (3) {\textbf{3} \\ Step};
\node[box=5cm, above right=of 3.south east] (4) {\textbf{4} \\ Step};
\node[box=6cm, above right=of 4.south east] (5) {\textbf{5} \\ Step};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
possible, slightly shorter code (after four years ...):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm,
                 minimum height=#1, align=center, anchor=south west},
node distance = 0mm and 5mm
                    ]
\node[box=2cm]                        (1) {\textbf{1} \\ Step};
\node[right=of 1.south east, box=3cm] (2) {\textbf{2} \\ Step};
\node[right=of 2.south east, box=4cm] (3) {\textbf{3} \\ Step};
\node[right=of 3.south east, box=5cm] (4) {\textbf{4} \\ Step};
\node[right=of 4.south east, box=6cm] (5) {\textbf{5} \\ Step};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: edit after another seven years - can we use `foreach ` in the above answer

Comment: @jsbibra, why not, but temporary I'm very busy  (with beamer which not going to work as I like ...).  At the first spare time.